# GoRouter - Using ShellRoute properly in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-go-router

I am using a ShellRoute within my GoRouter with those arguments:

```
final GoRouter _vamosRouter = GoRouter(
    debugLogDiagnostics: true,
    initialLocation: EventsPage.route,
    errorBuilder: (_, __) => const ErrorPage(),
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        path: LoginPage.route,
        builder: (_, __) => const LoginPage(),
        // redirect: (context, state) => context.read<UserViewModel>().isSignedIn ? EventsPage.route : null, // ändert nix
      ),
      ShellRoute(
        navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
        builder: (_, __, child) => RootPage(widget: child),
        routes: <RouteBase>[
          GoRoute(path: ProfilePage.route, builder: (_, __) => const ProfilePage()),
          GoRoute(path: OrganizationPage.route, builder: (_, __) => const OrganizationPage()),
          GoRoute(path: EventsPage.route, builder: (_, __) => const EventsPage()),
        ],
      ),
    ],
    redirect: (BuildContext context, _) => context.read<UserViewModel>().isSignedIn ? null : LoginPage.route,
  );
```

My Root Page looks like this:

```
class RootPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const RootPage({required this.widget});

  final Widget widget;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(children: [const Sidebar(), Expanded(child: widget)]),
    );
  }
}
```

So the basic layout is: a sidebar on the left side, and the main widget on the right site.

Problem: when switching between pages (or the main widget), the whole (RootPage) screen is built up again. How can I switch between pages in the ShellRoute with just the widget on the right site being reloaded?